# Using fopen, fwrite, fclose but file does not change

Tags: php, fopen

After PHP sub-program finishes, file remains unchanged.
Sorry including entitr code so I can show you debug output

Put in debug code. Used to create array and use file_put_contents but am trying to save memory space. code shown is without

```
<?php
function Reformat($Items,$FN)   {
    $FM=fopen('txt/$FN.txt','w');
    if ($FM===false)    {
        LOG_IT("open failed");
        return;
    }
    LOG_IT("open OK");
    $y = count($Items);
    $z=0;
    for ($x=0; $x < $y; $x++)   {
        $I=explode("|",$Items[$x]);
        if (count($I) < 4) continue;    $z++;
        $num=$I[4];$V=$I[5];$I2=$I[2];$I1=$I[1];$I0=$I[0];$I3=$I[3];
        $FN2="Comments/C$num";
        if (file_exists($FN2)) $C2="<a href='CommentL.php' onclick='Comm(this,$num,$V)'><button>See Comments</button></a>";
        else $C2 = "No Comments Yet";
        $c=fwrite($FM,"<tr onclick='Switch(\"$I2\")'><td class='HLL'><img src='$I1'></td><td class='HLR'><g>From: $I0</g><br>$I3<br><FL><a href='Comment.html' onclick='Comm(this,$num,$V)'><button>Make a Comment</button></a> $C2</FL></td></tr>\n");
        if (!$c)    LOG_IT("write failed");
    }
    LOG_IT("finished OK $z vs $y");
    $c=fclose($FM);
    LOG_IT("close=$c");
}
```

supposed to create a file of HTML code, one line for every input line (item in array). Debug output:

```
open OK
finished OK 84 vs 84
close=1
```

everything seem OK, but file hasn't changed

Comment: As your using single quotes in `'txt/$FN.txt'` - I would expect it to write to a file called txt/$FN.txt.  If this is the case then use double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It's work with - file created and changed)

```
$FM=fopen("txt/$FN.txt",'w');
```